# How do you create an AccountUser with SOAP (Successfully)?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an strange issue I'm encountering with creating an AccountUser with the SOAP API. The API returns an OverallStatus of "OK", but no user is ever created. The credentials I'm using can create users through the UI with no issue.

Anybody have any ideas or encountered similar?

```
   <createrequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
<Options/>
 <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Client>
       <ID>10894001</ID>
    </Client>
    <UserID>api2.jba</UserID>
    <Password>Password@1</Password>
    <Name>api2.jba</Name>
    <Email>test@bh.exacttarget.com</Email>
    <MustChangePassword>false</MustChangePassword>
    <DefaultBusinessUnit>10894001</DefaultBusinessUnit>
    <AssociatedBusinessUnits>
       <BusinessUnit>
          <ID>10894001</ID>
       </BusinessUnit>
    </AssociatedBusinessUnits>
 </Objects>
</createrequest>
```

Comment: I have tried following the [documented example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_a_new_user_to_an_existing_account.htm?search_text=adding%20new%20user) and get an `OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>` response, but I can't see the new user :-(

Comment: Thanks for giving it a spin, @EliotHarper. I get the same thing from a couple of accounts I've tried it on. Uuurgh!

Comment: I've tried different permutations of this request and get the same result each time. I'd open a support case on this if I were you. The documentation is incorrect and it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity...

```
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <Options>
    <SaveOptions>
      <SaveOption>
        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
        <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
      </SaveOption>
    </SaveOptions>
  </Options> 
  <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
    <Client>
      <ID>1234565</ID>
    </Client>
    <UserID>SampleUser</UserID>
    <Password>Password@1</Password>
    <Name>SampleUser</Name>
    <Email>test@somedomain.com</Email>
    <NotificationEmailAddress>test@somedomain.com</NotificationEmailAddress>
    <ActiveFlag>true</ActiveFlag>
    <IsAPIUser>true</IsAPIUser>
    <IsLocked>false</IsLocked>
    <MustChangePassword>true</MustChangePassword>
    <DefaultBusinessUnit>1234567</DefaultBusinessUnit>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <ObjectID>05245651-6447-e511-bb64-ac162dbd280c</ObjectID>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <ObjectID>11245651-6447-e511-bb64-ac162dbd280c</ObjectID>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
    <AssociatedBusinessUnits>
      <BusinessUnit>
        <CustomerKey>MyMIDCustomerKey</CustomerKey>
      </BusinessUnit>
    </AssociatedBusinessUnits>
  </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
```

Comment: For the BusinessUnit section and the MID, I think you have to specify it as ID, not CustomerKey.